# Should a man say a bracha if immersing in a mikvah?

Tags: blessing, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, mikvah-ritual-bath, men-male, contemporary-halacha

Should a man say a bracha, according to halachic sources, when immersing in a mikvah? (since there is no obligation on him).

Comment: For anything besides conversion, normative practice is to not make a blessing (since there is no obligation, as you pointed out)

Comment: What about when a man is obligated to immerse, such as after a nocturnal emission?

Comment: @Alexander 1) Strict halacha does not treat it as required today for any purpose, 2) but not sure if a blessing was made even when Ezra's decree was in force

Comment: @AKA I found a good challenge to that statement. Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 129:10 - If it is the night of the woman's immersion, he should not neglect the mitzvah of marital relations, and in the morning, he should immerse himself in the mivkah to cleanse himself from tumah (spiritual impurity).

Comment: @Alexander he should is different than he must

Comment: @AKA that's not true, sometimes a man is obligated today and would say a blessing. Anyway it's not obvious why an obligation matters; after all we say a blessing on shechita even though there's no obligation to eat meat.

Comment: NatanZ what do you mean "since there is no obligation"? Do you mean "when" instead of "since"? Or are you asking about a specific example where there is known to be no obligation?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Berakhot.22b.12.1?lang=bi

Comment: The rosh in yoma, in the 8th perek, perhaps siman 24 brings down from rav sadya goan, that on erev yom Kippur one should make a bracha after going to the mikva, however the rosh disagrees, and says no bracha should be made because it is not an obligation.

Comment: @DoubleAA when is a man obligated today? And I would assume if it would be a chiyuv he would make a bracha (like RSG says for erev YK, which we don't do, or tevilas ger) but not sure (as I pointed out - don't know if a bracha was ever made on tevilas Ezra).

Comment: @AKA the two standard answers are someone who is going on har habayit and a kohein who is going to eat challat chul. Maybe someone creative enough can find more. (I'm not discussing the politics of general aliya to har habayit, but everyone agrees at least in theory that a soldier who for pikuach nefesh reasons needs to go up there needs to dunk (time permitting).)

Comment: @DoubleAA never knew that! but makes sense - it's like shechita in that it's necessary do do something else, but tevilas Ezra/erev RH/YK is just a strong minhag/chumra, so we don't make a bracha.

Comment: Just saw Tosafos Pesachim 7b which is clear that they would make a bracha on tevilas BK, but that was when it was active I assume (as we don't)

Comment: As a parallel consideration on making a blessing when not obligated, consider the concept of a woman making the blessing when taking the lulav. They are clearly not obligated and yet according to Ashkenazi custom, they can make the blessing.

Answer (score 3):

The Mateh Efrayim [(606:17)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mateh_Efrayim.606.17?lang=bi) rules that even though there is a Mitzvah to toivel, one does not make a beracha.

> כל טבילות אלו שטובל בערב יום הכיפורים, אף על פי שהם מצוה, אינו מברך עליהם

Comment: This is only talking about Erev Yom Kippur and it's about both genders. (Granted the question wasn't very clear what it sought)